# combine rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two queries which return two different result one is return ex#1 return and second return ex#2, i want to combine and want desire result.

ex#1

```
PartyID    PartyName    TotalMain 
  1            A            1
  2            B            1
```

ex#2

```
PartyID    PartyName      TotalSub
  1            A              1
  3            C              1
```

and i want the result

```
 PartyID   PartyName       TotalMain             TotalSub
  1           A                 1                    1
  2           B                 1                    0
  3           C                 0                    1
```

Comment: -1, show us your queries and tables.  When asking a question, please think about what basic information YOU would need to solve the problem and provide it so we can help you.

Comment: @AbeMiessler  thanks for response.sorry i have no permission to show the query please use generic tables and solve the problem.

Comment: You can come up with dummy data and tables that will represent your problem.

Comment: @jam Nobody can solve the problem because you haven't described, at the very least, how you wish to get the TotalXXX columns (Count? Sum?), nor have you provided any feedback on the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with sample as 
(
SELECT 
e1.PartyID as partyid
,e1.PartyName as partyname
,e1.totalmain AS TotalMain
,0 AS TotalSub
From table1 e1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
e2.PartyID
,e2.PartyName
,0 AS TotalMain
,e2.totalsub AS TotalSub
From table2 e2
)
SELECT
partyid
,MAX(partyname) as partyname
,MAX(totalmain) as totalmain
,MAX(totalsub) as totalsub
from sample
GROUP BY
partyid
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your tables and current sql, all I can suggest is:

```
  Select Coalesce(a.PartyId, b.PartyId) partyId, 
       Coalesce(a.PartyName, b.PartyName) partyName, 
       a.TotalMain, b.TotalSub
  From ([Put First Query SQL Inside here]) a
      Full Join ([Put Second Query SQL Inside here]) b
         On a.PartyId = b.PartyId
```

Comment: This won't get the zeros in the desired output, though I realize the question is too vague right now.